# how to select all entries having date 25-11-20 in oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle

[sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDzFz.jpg)

here in the table above named carpooling contains a column name start_on which has date time as timestamp i have to write a query to select all the rows having date as 25-11-20 using to_char and to_date.

Comment: Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: its oracle oracle 11g

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots (or even worse photos), use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 1):

You write a [timestamp literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html) like this:

```
timestamp '2020-11-25 00:00:00'
```

so the full filtering condition will be

```
where start_on >= timestamp '2020-11-25 00:00:00'
and   start_on <  timestamp '2020-11-26 00:00:00'
```

Note that dates and timestamps are different in Oracle, and dates include times down to the second (this is for historical reasons - originally there was only the `date` type, and `timestamp` was added much later).

Answer (score 1):

Use the TRUNC function, along with date and interval literals:

```
SELECT *
  FROM CARPOOLING
  WHERE START_ON BETWEEN DATE '2020-11-25'
                     AND (DATE '2020-11-26' - INTERVAL '0.000001' SECOND)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use to_date, but it's recommended to remove the time when comparing the dates. Otherwise, rows having the same date, but a different time will not be selected. Removing the time can be done using TRUNC.
So you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM carpooling
WHERE TRUNC(start_on) = TO_DATE('2020-11-25','yyyy.mm.dd');
```

If you don't want to check the 25th of November 2020, but another data, change the date to match your goal.

Comment: How do you know `25-11-20` means `2020-11-25` and not `2025-11-20` or even `1920-11-25`?

Comment: I don't know this. The question was how to check whether rows match a given date and this explains how to do this. If the OP would like to check another date, he can just change it according to his desires.

Comment: How do you know he is a she

Comment: Your format string doesn't match your date format, it should be either `to_date( '2020-11-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` or `to_date( '2020.11.25', 'YYYY.MM.DD')`

Comment: @evilive you are right however, Oracle is quite tolerant in that regards and will accept this code.

Comment: @evilive: Both on my DB and on fiddle all these queries work fine. Anyway, there are lot of possibilities to achieve the OP's goal. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b65d207100501e9a5b9b15fad0cafc30

Comment: Wow, thank you. Really didn't know, that oracle is more tolerant than me, if a format was explictly defined ;)